# ERROR: Exception calling "SaveAs" with "2" argument(s): "SaveAs method of Workbook class failed"

Tags: 2010, powershell, timer-jobs

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I get following error when I try to save an Excel file via Power Shell:

```
ERROR: Exception calling "SaveAs" with "2" argument(s): "SaveAs method of Workbook class failed"
```

Command used for saving file is as follows:

```
$workbook.SaveAs(<FULL PATH WITH FILENAME>,1)
```

Above code works perfectly when I execute it via Power Shell console. But I am using [Ingo Karstein's](http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2011/08/04/sharepoint-powershell-timer-jobs-run-powershell-scripts-in-sharepoint-timer-service-context/)  utility to run Power Shell as Timer Job where this command fails. Other commands in script works fine, also it creates log,csv files without any issue. Issue occurs only while saving an Excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution to this answer [here](http://www.techdecode.com/wp/?p=58) and it works too !

Need to add following folder:

・**Windows 2008 Server x64**

Please make this folder.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

**・Windows 2008 Server x86**

Please make this folder.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop